# How to convert from list to ellipsis?

Tags: r

This answer [How to convert a list() to an ellipsis in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37118274/how-to-convert-a-list-to-an-ellipsis-in-r) is not satisfying, cuz it doesn't work for my issue:

#### Given:

```
foo <- function(...) {
  length(list(...))
}
```

#### When:

```
foo2 <- function(listArg) {
  # HERE convert from list to ...
  foo(...)
}
```

#### Then these all should be equal:

```
foo() == foo2(list())
foo(1, 2) == foo2(list(1, 2))
foo(1, 2, 3) == foo2(list(1, 2, 3))
```

What write in the `foo2` "# HERE convert from list to ..."

Comment: This edit is a big change to your question. You should not edit a question this much after it has been answered. You should ask a new question if your original question wasn't really the question you had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this answers your question:

```
foo <- function(...) length(list(...))
foo2 <- function(listArg) do.call(foo, listArg)

foo() == foo2(list())
# [1] TRUE
foo(1, 2) == foo2(list(1, 2))
# [1] TRUE
foo(1, 2, 3) == foo2(list(1, 2, 3))
# [1] TRUE
```

In this way we don't convert a list to ellipsis but rather call `foo` differently, by doing the conversion in the call.

Comment: yes it works, but didn't solve my problem, so I think I put bad question... I have a problem with `RJDBC::dbGetQuery(conn, stmt, listOfParams)` ERROR! and this `RJDBC::dbGetQuery(conn, stmt, param1, param2, param3)` OK... while `DBI::dbGetQuery(conn, stmt, listOfParams)` is OK

Comment: It's true that you should ask it as a separate question. But I'll guess that `do.call(RJDBC::dbGetQuery, c(conn, stmt, listOfParams))` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely use `do.call()` when you can.

We can make your code work with :

```r
list2dots <- function(x) {
  make_dots <- function(...) environment()$...
  do.call(make_dots, as.list(x))
}

foo <- function(...) {
  length(list(...))
}

foo2 <- function(listArg) {
  `...` <- list2dots(listArg)
  foo(...)
}

foo() == foo2(list())
#> [1] TRUE
foo(1, 2) == foo2(list(1, 2))
#> [1] TRUE
foo(1, 2, 3) == foo2(list(1, 2, 3))
#> [1] TRUE
```